# Existe uma forma para gerar versões releases nos Delphis antigos diretamente pela IDE?

Tags: delphi, compilação, delphi-7, release, delphi-2007

Nas versões mais recentes do Delphi podemos facilmente gerar uma versão do executável para distribuição bastando apenas executar a compilação pela opção **Release**.

Isso remove vários pontos uteis para o **debugger** e deixa o executável menor.

Existe essa forma de gerar executáveis para distribuição nas versões mais antigas do Delphi? Isso é baseado em configuração?

Gostaria de saber mais sobre as versões 6 e 7, pois ainda há sistemas nessas versões na empresa em que trabalho.

Geralmente usamos o `UPX` para conseguir executáveis menores, mas como fazer isso diretamente pela IDE como nas versões mais novas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Achei algumas informações interessantes.

> O delphi tb pode gerar executáveis menores, bastando para isto vc nao
>   usar a vcl, neste caso todos os eventos devem ser feitos na mao, tal
>   como no masm32, como os eventos de teclado, mouse, desenho da tela,
>   botoes e etc.  Claro que isto toma tempo, mas se a pessoa quer um
>   aplicativo que seja minúsculo, como um vírus por exemplo nao vai
>   utilizar de qualquer modo componentes visuais e tentara de todo modo
>   reduzir ao máximo a dependencia de terceiros, colocando as funçoes que
>   acessa numa unit separada em vez de adicionar toda a unit.

fonte: [ActiveDelphi](http://www.activedelphi.com.br/forum/viewtopic.php?t=66567&sid=9ea3a85f1251f0d1ec1b6d2f48302394). Resposta de **Johnny-Walker**.

Nesse mesmo post tem uma outra resposta, de **RodrigoPrado**

> -Aqui na empresa um .exe comum teria 60,7 mb. 
>   -otimizamos ele pra 30.0 
>   -depois disto ainda compactamos ele no 7Zip usando compactação modo ultra, fazendo o mesmo cair para 4,5 mb.
>
> então no final teriamos um arquivo.7z de 4,5 mb.
>
> 01-Usamos o delphi 7, em Project --- Options na page  DEBUGGING
>   desmarcamos todos os checks  ex: degug information, local symbols,
>   reference, definitions, assertions, use debug dcus.  02-na page LINKER
>   no group EXE AND DLL OPTION desmarcamos o generate consolte, o include
>   td32 debug e include remote debug simbols.
>
> ai clicamos ok, vamos em shift+f para da um build no exe novo, ele vai
>   cair pra menos da metade do pacote, pq nestas opões eh a versão do
>   usuario ai nao precisamos incluir nada de debug que usamos pra
>   desenvolvimento entre outras coisas.. .que soh existem pra gente que
>   desenvolve, pro usuario elel nao precisa disto ou seja so recebe o
>   codigo puro.